# ISE iMPACT program failing using Spartan-3AN

Tags: fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I would like to program my Xilinx Spartan-3AN using ISE but for the last step (using ISE iMPACT), the program is failing.

In fact I've put a ".bit" file into the first chip but I don't have any ".mcs" file to put into the second chip so I tried to bypass it.

Unfortunately, when I launch the program, it stays at 0% and after a few seconds a "Program Failed" appears on the screen.

I made a PrintScreen to help you to understand : 
[image: Printscreen of my problem](clickable)

Comment: You need to show us the error message produced when the programming fails; you can find this in the console after the "Program Failed" message has appeared, and it may be worth enlarging the console to more easily see what's in there. Also this issue has absolutely nothing to do with vhdl or verilog.

Comment: I changed that, sorry I'm new here but I'm learning...

Comment: Does the 'Read ID Code' function work properly? My best guess is that you've got a connectivity issue between your JTAG programmer and the FPGA; double check the circuit diagram and your JTAG header connections. It's also worth re-powering everything, and restarting Impact.

Comment: That function doesn't work... I'm not using JTAG, I'm trying to program it with USB

Comment: The FPGA doesn't have a USB interface, so at some point your programming goes via a JTAG bus. Check the circuit, or if it's a board that you bought, I suggest asking the company who sold you the board for help.

Comment: The first thing I would look at since the done pin isn't going high (see the log) is if you're using the correct bit file.  If you're loading data but the done pin doesn't go high it means you're probably not loading a valid image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my PROB_B pin was puled down to ground !